# How to make Flash ActiveX control compatible on deployment machine?

Tags: c#, .net, flash

The application used the ActiveX control axshockwaveflash, when you install and deploy the application on another machine there is a problem of compatibility version Flash, how to solve this problem? Can someone experienced in the past?

Comment: make friends ? really ?

Comment: I'm from Russia, I said something wrong? Then I'm sorry for my bad English. Make friends - that is, so as to combine these two technologies to be fitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello friend from Russia. I think you're seeking a solution to use both languages.

In fact, with C#, you can make Silverlight applications, which can do some of the functions that Flash provides, such as simple animations, form elements, and even camera & microphone. End users need to install Silverlight player in their browsers ( supported by Mac OS X & Windows ).

With Flash ( ActionScript ), you can make Flash animations as well as games. End users need to install Flash player in their browsers ( Google Chrome has built-in Flash player ).

In short, you need only either language to bring your contents to end users. No need to use ActiveX as it is commonly disabled / blocked by browsers.

Comment: I use WinForms, there is a component axshockwaveflash that I use, but he's having trouble installing and deploying the application on another computer, if the versions are the same with my flash, everything works, or does not work. How do I control version of the flash?

Comment: Convert WinForms ( time to update now , WinForms are really old ) to Silverlight programs. Then you can skip deployment issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice, I will be moving in the right direction, by the way, decided to install problem adobe flash active